# location.getLocation() does not access my location

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, location, flutter-futurebuilder

I use these packages
google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.3
flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
location: ^4.4.0
The fact is that when I test on the emulator, this command works correctly. She's tracking tracking location

```
await location.getLocation().then((locationn) {
    currentLocation = locationn;
  });
```

When I test on a real device, this also works, but I need to enable geolocation in advance and log in to google maps.
If I do not include geolocation in advance and request the user's location, this function will not work

```
Future<LocationData> getCurrentLocation() async {
Location location = Location();
try {
  await location.getLocation().then((locationn) {
    currentLocation = locationn;
  });
  location.onLocationChanged.listen(
        (newLoc) {
      currentLocation = newLoc;
    },
  );
} catch (e) {
  print('т $e');
}
notifyListeners();
return currentLocation;}
```

the program stops here in this line and does not move any further. There are no error messages

```
await location.getLocation().then((locationn) {
```

I'm doing the main function in future builder. here you can see that the maps are not displayed because of Marker() which requires my map coordinates

`(mapModel.currentLocation!.latitude!,  mapModel.currentLocation!.longitude!)`.

However, the get Current Location() function cannot return the current Location variable because, as I said earlier, for some reason it stops at the line

`await location.getLocation().then((locationn)`

```
FutureBuilder<LocationData>(
  future: mapModel.getCurrentLocation(),
  builder:(context, snapshot){
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    return GoogleMap(
      markers: {
        Marker(
          markerId: const MarkerId("currentLocation"),
          position: LatLng(mapModel.currentLocation!.latitude!, 
           mapModel.currentLocation!.longitude!),
        )
      },


position: LatLng(mapModel.currentLocation!.latitude!, 
           mapModel.currentLocation!.longitude!),
```

the manifest has all the necessary permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```